# Extension of an operator defined on (not necessarily closed) subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is there always an extension of an operator $T:U\rightarrow W$, defined on (not necessarily closed) subspaces of the infinitedimensional Hilbert spaces $H\supseteq U,L\supseteq W$, to the operator $$T':cl(U)\rightarrow cl(W),$$ where $cl$ denotes the closure.

Is this extension unique if we require uniform continuity ?

What about the case where $U$ is finite-dimensional ?

Comment: Well, in the finite-dimensional case every subspace is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Kevin already mentioned that the case where $U$ is finite dimensional is trivial.
- You can show that if $T$ is continuous (which implies that it is uniformly continuous) then there is a unique *continuous* extension.  This uses completeness of $L$.
- If $T$ is not continuous (or you do not care if the extension is continuous), and you are not asking for any particular properties of the extension, then this is a linear algebra problem.  If $\mathrm{cl}(U)=U + V$ with $V$ a subspace of $\mathrm{cl}(U)$ such that $U\cap V=\{0\}$, write $x\in \mathrm{cl}(U)$ as $x=u+v$ with $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, and define $T'(x)=T(u)$.  (The complementary subspace $V$ exists assuming the axiom of choice.)  Such an extension is not unique unless $U$ is closed.